# IIS Subapplication On Demand, A Chat Room Approach

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I want to create a Chat Room application in asp.net.
With following requirements:

1. On path '/ManageRooms' i want to be able to start and stop rooms.
   I want this part of the application to be independently deployable from the actual chat rooms.
2. Each Chat Room should be under its own path e.g. '/RoomA', '/RoomB' etc. and started on demand.
   Further more i do not want all rooms to run in the same executable.
   I would like to leave the logic splitting the room to IIS.

At first I thought about starting multiple instances of the room service as executables each having its own port. But i assume there is some more elegant way to do this with iis than this on.

Can anyone help me here or tell me where i should look for finding the right termologie?
Or am I doing some thing incredibly wrong with such an approach?

I thought about Subapplications but they seem not to be generated on demand and i wont be able to run to instances of the same application on the same server at the same time.
I also thougth this is a task microservices should be used for. But i did not find out how to create microsevrices for IIS with asp.net and how to host them correctly.

Comment: "i do not want all rooms to run in the same executable" - it would be interesting to know where this requirement is coming from and the underlying problem(s) it's meant to be addressing.

Comment: I want to avoid 2 things. Since it is not a pure chat app, one client in each room is a IoT device sending loads of data which need to be processed by the services. 
Then users can ask the service question for the processing results of a specific sensor and give hints for further processing.
On such service is very memory hungry thats why i would like to have them in different processes to be later able to add additional servers for loadbalancing. 
The service only uses in memory data and should shut down it self when done.

Comment: there is no direct way but you use some c# code or PowerShell script to create application or site in iis